# What is the way to remove www from a domain - htaccess is not helping too

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

My SSL only covers swellnomore.com, not www.swellnomore.com.

I get a security error when i type https://www.swellnomore.com. Can this be fixed (forwarded to https://swellnomore.com ?

I had tried putting the following to htacess but did not helped too

```
# Override GoDaddy defaults that inhibit URL rewriting
Options -MultiViews
rewriteEngine On

# Rewrite URLs to remove www from domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Before putting the above , htaccess looked like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^swellnomore.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/swellnomore\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

P.S , I had already changed the site domain to 
https://swellnomore.com in wp dashboard > general settings.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would recommend using .htaccess for this, rather than configuring Apache correctly in the first place.

Comment: mevius can You please elaborate ? I am a newbie and do not have this advanced knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite the domain , you should rewrite to https not to http
Try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

whole htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] 

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: That did not worked too. Is there anything I need to remove from the orignal htaccess before placing this redirect code ?

Comment: replace you whole .htaccess file with this code in my post

Comment: Ok the update worked but just half , Now www.swellnomore.com is working fine and redirecting to https:// swellnomore.com/ but https:// www.swellnomore.com/ is still giving the error , How can I redirect https:// www.swellnomore.com/ to https:// swellnomore.com/ ?

Comment: thats caused by RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on , delete this line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to put this `.htaccess` in your root folder :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://sub.domain.com/this [L]
```

try this javascript

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
      if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/");
      </script>
```

**Note : where / is the path u want to show.**

it shows the url like `mysite.com`   no matter which link i have clicked. but i have a problem with this code while reloading the page the complete url with query string blink into address bar.

### Update

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Example: http://www.addondomain.com/projects/a/gallery/4/2 -> http://addondomain.com/projects/a/gallery/4/2

Comment: Where do I paste it ? Header ?

Comment: try out with `.htaccess` if it doesn't works comment

Comment: When I added it to htaccess , it did not solved the problem, instead gave me error on https://swellnomore.com/


Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@swellnomore.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an

Comment: Ok the update worked but just half , Now www.swellnomore.com is working fine and redirecting to https://  swellnomore.com/ but https://  www.swellnomore.com/ is still giving the error , How can I redirect https://  www.swellnomore.com/ to https://  swellnomore.com/ ?

Comment: but both url are same

Comment: https is causing the problem , please click the url with and without https and see for Your self

Comment: in quetsion **What is the way to remove www from a domain - `htaccess` is not helping too** but you didn't mention about redirect so you got your answer if you need to redirect ask new question everyone will help you its nice question

Comment: the question is

I get a security error when i type https:// www.swellnomore.com. Can this be fixed (forwarded to https:// swellnomore.com ?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

Add this to your `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```